# Mips assembly conversion to C

Tags: c, assembly, mips

How can this be written in C and what should the solution be if $a0 = 43981 ?

```
srl $v0, $a0, 4
andi $v0, $v0, 255
```

I did this, but it doesn't seem to produce the expected value. input in this case is 43981 and it prints 0 for v

```
int v = input >> 4;
v = v & 225;
```

Comment: Please state specifically what you don't understand rather than just dumping your work and expecting someone else to do it for you. Do you not understand the mips assembly syntax? Do you not understand how to write C? What is it specifically that is preventing you from doing your own work?

Comment: @kaylum I just did

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work". Please explain exactly why. What did you expect and what actually was the result? And what is the value of `input`?

Comment: @kaylum it prints 0 for v and input is 43981

Comment: what output did you expect?

Comment: `(43981>>4 ) & 225` is 160.  `(43981>>4 ) & 0xff` is 188.  If you're getting 0, the problem is somewhere else in your C.  Thus, this is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Note that `srl` is *shift right logical* (i.e.) it is *unsigned*. Also, in your C, you are masking against `225` instead of `255`

So, you probably want:

```
int v = (unsigned) input >> 4;
v = v & 255;
```